# Adi-method for Diffusion-reaction equation in 2d

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

i'm trying to solve this pde using an adi-method (alternating-direction-implicit).

$\frac{d f}{d t}=D\nabla^2_{x,y} f+Q(x,y)f+C$

After discretizing, the equation looks like this.

Implicit in x-direction and explicit in y-direction :

(1) $\ \frac{f_{j,k}^{i+{1/2}}-f_{j,k}^i}{\Delta t/2}=\frac{D}{\Delta s²}[(f_{j-1,k}^{i+{1/2}}-2f_{j,k}^{i+{1/2}}+f_{j+1,k}^{i+{1/2}})+(f_{j,k-1}^{i}-2f_{j,k}^{i}+f_{j,k+1}^{i})]+Qf_{j,k}^?+C$

Then implicit in y-direction and explicit in x-direction :

(2) $\ \frac{f_{j,k}^{i+1}-f_{j,k}^{i+{1/2}}}{\Delta t/2}=\frac{D}{\Delta s²}[(f_{j-1,k}^{i+{1/2}}-2f_{j,k}^{i+{1/2}}+f_{j+1,k}^{i+{1/2}})+(f_{j,k-1}^{i+1}-2f_{j,k}^{i+1}+f_{j,k+1}^{i+1})]+Qf_{j,k}^?+C$

with $\ \Delta x= \Delta y= \Delta s $

Now my question is, how do i evaluate the term $\ Q f^?_{j,k}$

For equation (1) ? could be either i or i+1/2 and for (2) it could be either i+1/2 or  i+1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the $Q$ is negative it is wise to take the term implicitly. If it is positive, I would take both with halves and hope for the second order

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try that. But is there a reason to do it this way, or is this from  your own experience?

Comment: If $Q$ is a big negative number then the ODE part of the equation is stiff and should be treated accordingly. Integrating that term explicitly may require very small timestep. Sure, that depends on the actual numerical value of $Q$. Also using $\frac{f^{i+1/2} + f^{i}}{2}$ for $f^{?}_{j,k}$ might be the best, since it is both A-stable and second order method

Comment: And $Q\frac{f^{i+1/2}+f^{i+1}}{2}$ for the second half step

Comment: Yes $\ Q$ is negativ and big compared to $\ f $(positiv).So i get:              (1) $\ \frac{f_{j,k}^{i+{1/2}}-f_{j,k}^i}{\Delta t/2}=\frac{D}{\Delta s²}[(f_{j-1,k}^{i+{1/2}}-2f_{j,k}^{i+{1/2}}+f_{j+1,k}^{i+{1/2}})+(f_{j,k-1}^{i}-2f_{j,k}^{i}+f_{j,k+1}^{i})]+\frac{Qf_{j,k}^{i+1/2}+Qf_{j,k}^{i}}{2}+C$




      (2) $\ \frac{f_{j,k}^{i+1}-f_{j,k}^{i+{1/2}}}{\Delta t/2}=\frac{D}{\Delta s²}[(f_{j-1,k}^{i+{1/2}}-2f_{j,k}^{i+{1/2}}+f_{j+1,k}^{i+{1/2}})+(f_{j,k-1}^{i+1}-2f_{j,k}^{i+1}+f_{j,k+1}^{i+1})]+\frac{Qf_{j,k}^{i+1/2}+Qf_{j,k}^{i+1}}{2}+C$

Comment: Should work well IMO

Comment: Ok Thank you very much ill try it.

Comment: If it fails you can try fully implicit approximation of that term, that would be $Qf^{i+1/2}$ for the (1) and $Qf^{i+1}$ for the (2)